# How to align a character on 2D planet to be upright on the planet's surface?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a planet with its own gravity and I have a character who sticks to the surface of the planet. Now I want him to always be upright on his feet (standing up).

Here's a picture of his current state - he isn't standing on his feet:

[image: he is not on his feet, i want he align correct]

This is my code:

```
void Update () {
    Vector2 difference = planet.transform.position - this.transform.position;
    rb.AddForce((difference).normalized * gravitypull);
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(difference.x, difference.y);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just align the character's upwards direction to the direction of the gravitational pull - no need for any complex angle calculations, leave it to the game engine! So add something like this:

```cs
// May need to be -difference because of how you calculated the vector
transform.up = difference;
```

If your planet isn't going to be perfectly circular, or the surface is going to have obstacles/irregularities which will required the character to not stand perfectly "up", then you'll instead need to get the normal vector of the surface on which the character is standing, and align the character to that. (Note that a non-circular planet will probably also have implications on the gravity calculation.)